# Cannot install Scrapy 0.18 on Mac OS 10.8.4 running Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, scrapy, unpack

I have installed both pip and easy_install on my MacBook Pro running Mac OS 10.8.4 and Python 3.3. When I try and use pip to install Scrapy (http://scrapy.org/), I receive the error message shown at the bottom. I receive a similar error message with easy_install. I initially assumed that something was wrong with the Scrapy installation process specifically but it appears that I am unable to install any Python packages. I just installed Python today so I have not successfully installed any Python packages ever on this machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Downloading/unpacking Scrapy

 Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/
 URLs to search for versions for Scrapy:
 * https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.16.3.tar.gz#md5=cdc9dcea352d66ccfa266bb049006cca (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.16.3
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.7.tar.gz#md5=11710c73ff74dc61c2c68cdc7fdd978a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.7
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.9.win32.exe#md5=35c412031e87609a17560d3e50d7edde (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.12.0.2550.tar.gz#md5=484059cc53d761c13309eb426e238702 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.12.0.2550
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.14.1.tar.gz#md5=104c36b65c6e69fcbe79612fea1d71bd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.14.1
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.14.1.win32.exe#md5=48df2ba8404bef75bbabf41d7a50156e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.8.win32.exe#md5=cb41af67bd0f56ce815af9bb596238ec (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.9.tar.gz#md5=4f2db6ad091119a7b80cf64cb5bb4db0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.9
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.16.2.tar.gz#md5=0abae280db82f22952f336537ac13454 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.16.2
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.7.win32.exe#md5=10b916054d8a554348c2ff7bf435b50d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.16.0.tar.gz#md5=ebdfcfd29b82f987ccbc484fce4ab119 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.16.0
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.14.3.win32.exe#md5=5a143abd7e492961c8f2f2fd77ad189f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.14.2.tar.gz#md5=aefc425cf5eea31eae029146cf8a8755 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.14.2
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.10.4.2364.tar.gz#md5=bbf6825649990f530897464f556d731f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.10.4.2364
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.8.tar.gz#md5=d8b1e78d15cb99229438f1211e8d96f8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.8
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.14.4.tar.gz#md5=746868cb92b8a1fbae9fc7e04ce436a5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.14.4
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.14.2.win32.exe#md5=d6afe69f0920d93c55ea6f3fd639ba4a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.16.1.tar.gz#md5=6ecf312070c049d222f1271060cbb7a5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.16.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.14.3.tar.gz#md5=59f1225f7692f28fa0f78db3d34b3850 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.14.3
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.16.5.tar.gz#md5=0033f713509fb39c92d182ea11836b62 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.16.5
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.18.0.tar.gz#md5=5600a39ceaba12742dc55ba3b6748b7c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.18.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.16.4.tar.gz#md5=a82c56a9a17cf5dff57c241c40bcb664 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/), version: 0.16.4
 Using version 0.18.0 (newest of versions: 0.18.0, 0.16.5, 0.16.4, 0.16.3, 0.16.2, 0.16.1, 0.16.0, 0.14.4, 0.14.3, 0.14.2, 0.14.1, 0.12.0.2550, 0.10.4.2364, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.18.0.tar.gz#md5=5600a39ceaba12742dc55ba3b6748b7c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/)
 Running setup.py egg_info for package Scrapy

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/86/1mln902j0jx7698nxqk69_7r0000gn/T/pip_build_zacharygallinger/Scrapy/setup.py", line 67, in <module>

    data = [f for f in filenames if is_not_module(f)]

     File "/private/var/folders/86/1mln902j0jx7698nxqk69_7r0000gn/T/pip_build_zacharygallinger/Scrapy/setup.py", line 67, in <listcomp>

    data = [f for f in filenames if is_not_module(f)]

  File "/private/var/folders/86/1mln902j0jx7698nxqk69_7r0000gn/T/pip_build_zacharygallinger/Scrapy/setup.py", line 58, in is_not_module

    return os.path.splitext(f)[1] not in ['.py', '.pyc', '.pyo']

NameError: global name 'f' is not defined

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File    "/private/var/folders/86/1mln902j0jx7698nxqk69_7r0000gn/T/pip_build_zacharygallinger/Scrapy/setup.py", line 67, in <module>

  data = [f for f in filenames if is_not_module(f)]

 File "/private/var/folders/86/1mln902j0jx7698nxqk69_7r0000gn/T/pip_build_zacharygallinger/Scrapy/setup.py", line 67, in <listcomp>

   data = [f for f in filenames if is_not_module(f)]

 File "/private/var/folders/86/1mln902j0jx7698nxqk69_7r0000gn/T/pip_build_zacharygallinger/Scrapy/setup.py", line 58, in is_not_module

   return os.path.splitext(f)[1] not in ['.py', '.pyc', '.pyo']

NameError: global name 'f' is not defined
```

---

Cleaning up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/intro/install.html states scrapy requires 2.6 or 2.7.  I can't find anything saying it can run with a later version of python.  You might want to try installing python 2.7 in addition to 3.3, then using virualenv to run scrapy.